# C Macro's Using '##' and '###' also pointers

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, hook

I know what most of this macro is doing. But for the triple '###'s. I know what double '##' do. Its just joining the words/numbers together.

But I've never seen triple '###'s together till now.

```
#define HOOK(library, funcname) {L###library, #funcname, NULL, \
&New_##funcname, (void **) &Old_##funcname}
```

I also would like to know what this macro is doing.

```
#define HOOKDEF( return_value, calling_convention, apiname, ... ) \
return_value ( calling_convention *Old_##apiname )( __VA_ARGS__ ); \
return_value calling_convention New_##apiname( __VA_ARGS__ )
```

I know the macro is a function pointer macro. But I don't understand this part after the ';'

```
return_value calling_convention New_##apiname( __VA_ARGS__ )
```

I know it would join New_apiname.. But I don't see the word New_ in any of the code.

Example of HOOKDEF:

```
HOOKDEF(int, WSAAPI, getaddrinfo,
_In_opt_  PCSTR pNodeName,
_In_opt_  PCSTR pServiceName,
_In_opt_  const ADDRINFOA *pHints,
_Out_     PADDRINFOA *ppResult
) {
IS_SUCCESS_ZERO();

BOOL ret = Old_getaddrinfo(pNodeName, pServiceName, pHints, ppResult);
LOQ("ss", "NodeName", pNodeName, "ServiceName", pServiceName);
return ret;
}
```

What I'm not understanding is where is the New_apifunc() suppose to come into play?

Is that macro making the HOOKDEF the New_apifunc() automatically?

because normally you would hooking something like this:

```
#define HOOK( func, addy )  o##func = ( func##_t )DetourFunction( (PBYTE)addy, (PBYTE)hk##func )    

// --- HOOK DRAW INDEXED PRIMITIVE ---
HRESULT WINAPI hkDrawIndexedPrimitive( LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pDevice, D3DPRIMITIVETYPE PrimType, INT BaseVertexIndex, UINT MinVertexIndex, UINT NumVertices, UINT startIndex, UINT primCount )
{
    __asm nop   

    // Do whatever...

    return oDrawIndexedPrimitive( pDevice, PrimType, BaseVertexIndex, MinVertexIndex, NumVertices, startIndex, primCount );

}// END HOOK DRAW INDEXED PRIMITIVE
```

In this example you can clearly see the new hkfunc() and the old ofunc() within the macro.

But I'm thinking that HOOKDEF is the hooked function. I'm I right ?

Answer (score 1):

`###` isn't anything special, it's just `##` followed by `#`. `##` is for concatenation, `#` is for stringizing, so `L ## # x` can<sup>1</sup> become `L"x"`.

As for `HOOKDEF`, `New_...` doesn't get used there. As far as I can tell, it just declares `Old_...` and defines `New_...`. I suspect there is some extra part of the code, that is missing for your question, that makes all calls to `getaddrinfo` *actually* call `New_getaddrinfo` without the caller being aware of it.

Actually, looking closer, that seems to be what your `HOOK` macro is for, that also prepends `New_` to a function name the same way, and would allow its user to see the new function.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Strictly speaking, it is not required to work unless the compiler processes the `#` before the `##`, but your compiler will do what the author of this code expected it to.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, what about the definition for the New_func() ? In that particular code is it even using it?

Comment: @user3345770 Not that I can tell, I've now addressed that in my answer.

Comment: I think HOOKDEF() is morphing into the format int WSAAPI New_getaddrinfo( _In_opt_  PCSTR pNodeName, _In_opt_  PCSTR pServiceName, _In_opt_  const DDRINFOA *pHints, _Out_     PADDRINFOA *ppResult ) and that is why there is no need for a New_func()... I'm pretty sure thats what it is doing. Its a pretty brillant macro.

Comment: @user3345770 Yes, it defines `New_getaddrinfo`, but unless it actually gets used, that function would just sit there waiting for someone to call it. :) But the use of that function is hidden through use of the `HOOK` macro.

Comment: Well what I'm saying is it gets called by the HOOK() macro. HOOKDEF() just morphes into New_func... Meaning its masked less coding. No need for a hkfunction or newfunc because HOOKDEF is it.

Comment: @user3345770 Okay, then we just had some miscommunication, we do mean the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I kinda thought that was what it was doing but I wasn't sure. I'm sure now. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Actually, this is wrong.  The standard says that the precedence between `#` and `##` is unspecified, so the compiler could do the concatenation first, resulting in `L#`, which isn't a legal token, so results in undefined behavior.  (Of course, if this is in a system dependent header, and the implementation defines the behavior, it's fine.  But otherwise, no.)

Comment: @JamesKanze No, this answer is correct. I was already aware of that problem but weighed this question as one that wouldn't benefit from those details, so worded my answer to avoid that problem. `L ## # x` can become `L"x"`. It isn't required to, but it can.

Comment: @hvd Since there's undefined behavior, it _can_ become anything:-).  So yes.  But that "can" is pretty hidden; it would be worth pointing out that it isn't guaranteed.  (Although it works with g++, which is about the only compiler I know which actually does have an issue if the result of `##` isn't a token.  So g++ seems to be doing `#` before `##`, or it's dropped this check.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Whether there's undefined behaviour is unspecified. If the compiler does do `#` before `##`, no undefined behaviour follows. This is what GCC does, as you rightly suggested. clang also doesn't accept `##` when the result isn't a token, but also does `#` before `##`. Visual Studio, which the OP is using according to the tags, might not, but accepts uses of `##` that don't form a valid token. And the code certainly doesn't look like it's meant to be portable to other implementations. But okay, will add a note.